# HibernateSearch - Modify the StandardTokenizerFactory to concatenate all words

Tags: java, solr, lucene, tokenize, hibernate-search

I'm using the `StandardTokenizerFactory` as my `@TokenizerDef` in my Hibernate class. I would like to keep the way the `StandardTokenizerFactory` tokenizes words but add another rule to create a token by concatenating (specfically removes all spaces) all the words in a field.

What is the easiest way or any alternatives methods to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is another token filter (factory) in your filter chain. Have you had a look at ShingleFilterFactory? It does something very similar and the token separator can be configured. Not sure whether it can be the empty string as well. If nothing else you can write your own ConcatenatingFilterFactory based on ShingleFilterFactory.